# Leetcode #377 Dynamic Programming Logic Question

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have been struggling to comprehend one of the discussion solutions shown from [LC #377](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/). I'm not grasping how result is being incremented. I can see that there is the line:

> result += combinations(nums, dp, target - nums[i])

which obviously is incrementing result, but *how exactly is result being incremented?* All I can see that is result is initialized to 0 then the line is executed if that if condition is satisfied, so wouldn't the line:

> dp[target] = result

always be set to 0?. Really struggling comprehending, so would appreciate any help.

Code:

```
class Solution {
public int combinationSum4(int[] nums, int target) {
    int[] dp = new int[target + 1];
    Arrays.fill(dp, -1);
    dp[0] = 1;
    return combinations(nums, dp, target);
}

public int combinations(int[] nums, int[] dp, int target) {
    if (dp[target] != -1) {
        return dp[target];
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (target >= nums[i]) {
            result += combinations(nums, dp, target - nums[i]);
        }
    }
    dp[target] = result;
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: This is an example of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing reply on your question around `result` being incremented.
This is the code you mentioned:

```
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (target >= nums[i]) {
            result += combinations(nums, dp, target - nums[i]);
        }
    }
    dp[target] = result;
```

There is a `for` loop that increments `i` from `0` to `nums.length-1`. For each such `i`, if this condition is met `(target >= nums[i])`, then `result` is updated by each call to `combinations(nums, dp, target - nums[i])`. You can see from the signature that `combinations()` returns an `int` value.

When `dp[target] = result` is reached, the `result` has sum of the values returned by each of the calls to `combinations()`.

The following code may help you. It counts the total even numbers between `1` to `n`. I wrote it to match the flavor of recursion used in your post. Hope it helps.

```
public class SumDemo {
    int checkEven(int n) {
        return (n % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    int countEven(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
            result += checkEven(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumDemo demo = new SumDemo();
        System.out.println(demo.countEven(10));
    }
}

Result:
5
```

(Since there are 5 even numbers between 1 to 10 (both inclusive)): 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

Comment: thanks! so, more or less, for every iteration checkEven(i) is called, result is being incremented by one?

Comment: The `checkEven()` method will return `1` (if number is even), or `0` (if number is odd). Hence, `result` is incremented by `0` or `1` each time.

Comment: I made an edit in `checkEven()` method to indicate the return value. Hopefully, this makes it more clear.